# Installing NVIDIA driver on EKS nodes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-web-services, eks

I have a EKS cluster that has two node pools. One CPU general compute, the other one has GPU support (g4dn). I want to install NVIDIA driver on to the GPU node group. The best I can do right now is to manually ssh onto each node and install. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Not a devops specialist so apologize in advance if question is ill formed

Answer (score 1):

[GPU Operator](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-gpu-operator-simplifying-gpu-management-in-kubernetes/) helps manage NVIDIA drivers in Kubernetes clusters, you can deploy it using [Helm](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/gpu-operator/getting-started.html#install-nvidia-gpu-operator).